# i want to set label for category and number axis in barchart

Tags: javafx

```
        barList.add(new BarChart<String,Number>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis()));

        seriesList.add(new XYChart.Series()); 
        for (int hh = 0; hh < 11; hh++) {
            seriesList.get(i).getData().add(new XYChart.Data(chartOverallListX.get(i).get(hh), chartOverallListY.get(i).get(hh).doubleValue()));
            }

        barList.get(i).getData().addAll(seriesList.get(i));

        barList.get(i).setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;");
        paneList.get(i).getChildren().addAll(barList.get(i));
```

I would like to add **labels** and **colour** for the category and number axis. What I have done here is created a List of ten `BarChart`s by looping through and adding the chart and its data to separate lists. These  lists are added to a List of Panes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what's being asked here but to set axis labels you can use these methods:

```
barList.get(i).getXAxis().setLabel("X axis label");
barList.get(i).getYAxis().setLabel("Y axis label");
```

Comment: thanks. it worked.. how to set color and font for that label being set. any idea..?

Comment: barList.get(i).getXAxis().setLabel("Xlabel");
            barList.get(i).getXAxis().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;");   is this okay..?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Although setting to white may make the text invisible if its on a white background; so perhaps "-fx-text-fill: #4682b4;"?